# How to get parameters of v4l2 in android camera?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2, v4l2

I want to use below properties using V4l2.How can i get & set this properties in android ??
For reference I am using below link but I don't understand how to set below parameters.
[Android_v4l2_camra](https://github.com/shengjunhu/android_v4l2_camera).

```
v4l2-ctl --device=$1 -v
width=1920
height=1080
pixelformat=MJPG
brightness=0
contrast=32
saturation=64
hue=0
white_balance_temperature_auto=1
gamma=300
power_line_frequency=0
sharpness=80
backlight_compensation=2
exposure_auto=3
exposure_auto_priority=0
pan_absolute=0
tilt_absolute=0
zoom_absolute=0
version
```